# Can't see the sidebar in geany 1.27 on mac

Tags: macos, user-interface, geany

I can't see the sidebar in geany 1.27 on Mac OS. Because of this I have no way of seeing the symbol list or document list

Is there a configuration option or else I missed ?

Answer (score 1):

Close Geany, then in `.config/geany/geany.conf` inside your home dir, set

```
treeview_position=100
```

and restart Geany.

When sidebar is collapsed, you can't restore it from the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Per default it should be visible. Check `.config/geany/geany.conf` inside your home with e.g. vim for this options I could imaging of maybe causing the issue

```
tab_pos_sidebar=2
sidebar_pos=0
sidebar_symbol_visible=true
sidebar_openfiles_visible=true
sidebar_visible=true
```

(these values are actually taken from my working OS X configuration of Geany. I'm referring to config file as its much fast the double check than go there click here)

Comment: I have the same values set ...still no sidebar

Installed last 1.27 version no sidebar